# ReactRouter 4 redirect to Home page on other routs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

On my React application if the user is logged in I want to show a set of components and if not logged in another set of components. Now I want to redirect any other paths to the `GuestUser`component which is also one of the exact paths.

```
      <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            {LoggedIn? (
              <div className="app-content">{this.getRoutes()}</div>
            ) : (
                <div className="app-content">{this.getGuestRoutes()}</div>
            )}
            <Footer />
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
```

the `Guest Routes` are like

```
  private getGuestRoutes() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route path={'/:id'} exact component={GuestUser} />
        <Route path={'/:id/policy'} exact component={...}/>
        <Route path={'/:id/signIn'} exact component={...} />
        <Route component={GuestUser} />
      </React.Fragment>
   );}
```

In many questions, I see that writing `<Route component={GuestUser} />` should render `GuestUser` component on any other paths rather than the exact ones. But what I see is that the `GuestUser` component renders on the bottom/beneath other components on every path.

Is the problem here with `React.Fragment`? 
How should redirect/render a specific component on any other path except the exact ones?

Comment: Can you please share the complete code of your `GuestUser` component?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your `<Route>`s with `<Switch>` to be sure that only one of them will be rendered.

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

<Switch>
  <Route path={'/:id'} exact component={GuestUser} />
  <Route path={'/:id/policy'} exact component={...}/>
  <Route path={'/:id/signIn'} exact component={...} />
  <Route component={GuestUser} />
</Switch>
```